# Slow reads and slow boot in windows 10

Tags: windows, ssd, performance

I'm using two partitions of half of a Crucial BX500 1 TB SSD (ct960bx500ssd1) each to boot Windows or Ubuntu. While I have seen Windows performance in reads to degrade significatively, Ubuntu still runs normally.

This is affecting both booting Windows and running software after the boot completed.

I ran a CrystalDiskMark benchmark over the disk and these are the results:

[image: CrystalDiskMark benchmark]

Is the SSD getting old?
How could I diagnose, and understand better what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Have you updated your Windows and your drivers ?
You can use Driver Easy tool to update your drivers.

Also, update your Bios